# Facebook JavaScript SDK Login

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Here's my code. It works perfectly on Facebook's JavaScript SDK test console, but not here :    http://www.booktrolley.in/beta/fblogin.php

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"> 
<head></head> 
<body> 
<div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
<script> 
FB.init({
  appId  : '270423476307006',
 status : true, // check login status
 cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
 xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
channelUrl : 'http://pedurology.org/booktrolley/beta/channel.html', // channel.html file
oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
});
</script> 

<h1>Login, Logout, Name and Profile Picture</h1> 
<div id="account-info"></div> 

<script> 
/**
 * This assumes the user is logged in and renders their profile picture,
 * name and a logout link.
*/
  function showAccountInfo() {
  FB.api(
 {
   method: 'fql.query',
  query: 'SELECT name,uid,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid='+FB.getSession().uid
 },
 function(response) {
 alert(FB.getSession().uid);
  Log.info('API Callback', response);
  document.getElementById('account-info').innerHTML = (

    '<img src="' + response[0].pic_square + '"> ' +
    response[0].name +
    ' <img onclick="FB.logout()" style="cursor: pointer;"' +
        'src="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">'
   );
  }
  );
}

/**
 * This assumes the user is logged out, and renders a login button.
 */
 function showLoginButton() {
   document.getElementById('account-info').innerHTML = (
 '<img onclick="FB.login()" style="cursor: pointer;"' +
     'src="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">'
  );
}

/**
* This will be called once on page load, and every time the status changes.
*/
function onStatus(response) {
Log.info('onStatus', response);
if (response.session) {
 showAccountInfo();
  } else {
  showLoginButton();
 }
 }
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  onStatus(response); // once on page load
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatus); // every status change
 });
 </script> 
  </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi again :) I still think that calling your app from a different domain other that the one it's originally pointing to IS the problem. Try creating the same page that is on `pedurology.org` on your app domain `www.booktrolley.in` and see the result of that.

Comment: @ifaour Hey :D All my data is on pedurology.org itself,and my i changed my app domain to pedurology.org as you had suggested,the previous problem got solved.
But not this one.

Thanks for your reply :D

Comment: or you could change your site, domain urls in your app settings to `pedurology.org` and try that.

Comment: @ifaour : Yes i tried that, but that didn't help :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting a "Log is undefined" error in the following code:

```
function onStatus(response) {
Log.info('onStatus', response);
if (response.session) {
 showAccountInfo();
  } else {
  showLoginButton();
 }
 }
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  onStatus(response); // once on page load
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatus); // every status change
 });
```

you trying to make use of a logger that exists on FB's page, but not on your own?

Comment: i'm sorry , i don't really understand the code that well. What's - logger  here ?

Comment: Log is some custom logger Facebook built into their test page.  Is writing debug info to either your browser's console, or some hidden div on the page.  Either way, the logger isn't defined on your page, so your script breaks before it has a chance to do anything.  Take out the Log.info('onStatus', response); line, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId: '270423476307006',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        oauth: true
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        onStatus(response); // once on page load
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', onStatus); // every status change
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
</script>

<h1>Login, Logout, Name and Profile Picture</h1>
<div id="account-info"></div>

<script>
/**
 * This assumes the user is logged in and renders their profile picture,
 * name and a logout link.
 */
function showAccountInfo(resp) {
    if( !resp.userID ) {
        // we shouldn't be here
        return;
    }
    FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT name,uid,pic_square FROM user WHERE uid='+resp.userID
    },
    function(response) {
      document.getElementById('account-info').innerHTML = (

        '<img src="' + response[0].pic_square + '"> ' +
        response[0].name +
        ' <img onclick="FB.logout()" style="cursor: pointer;"' +
            'src="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/z2Y31/hash/cxrz4k7j.gif">'
      );
    }
    );
}

/**
 * This assumes the user is logged out, and renders a login button.
 */
function showLoginButton() {
  document.getElementById('account-info').innerHTML = (
    '<img onclick="FB.login()" style="cursor: pointer;"' +
         'src="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zB6N8/hash/4li2k73z.gif">'
  );
}

/**
 * This will be called once on page load, and every time the status changes.
 */
function onStatus(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    showAccountInfo(response.authResponse);
  } else {
    showLoginButton();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Now let's explain what we've done:

1. We are using Asynchronous loading to insure that `FB.getLoginStatus()` will get fired ONLY when the library is successfully loaded
2. Since you are setting `oauth` to true then you need to change your code to work with the new responses (refer to this [post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/)) (you may need to change your app settings)
3. Based on #2, the current user ID to use in your `showAccountInfo()` will be accessible using `response.authResponse.userID`